# Google Analytics and Webmasters Tool configurations for multidomain site platform

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

I'm trying to build a multi domain site platform where, basically like Wordpress.com, where user can sign up for new site and they can post contents under different domain with other users. At first it will be under a subdomain of the product website (e.g. the product's domain is `www.example.com`, and domain for the `user1` is `user1.example.com`). But user can choose to use her own domain (e.g. user using `user1.example.com` can use `www.my-domain-example.com`).

Here are my questions:

1. Can I use same the Google Analytics and Webmaster Tools account for all of the website, no matter if the user choose to use totally different domain name?
2. How should I setup the sitemap on the Webmaster Tools for all of the websites? Where should I put the sitemap file? On `www.example.com/sitemap.xml` for all of the websites, or at each sites `user1.example.com/sitemap.xml`? If the case is the latter, how do I submit the sitemap every time a new user sign up for a new site?
3. If one day I allow the users to put their own Google Analytics tracking code so that they can see the performance in their own Google Analytics panel, can I still put my tracker so that I can see in mine?
4. Is there something else that I should be aware of?

Thanks!